# Value not deciphered

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to print the value in BUILD_VER using below code,for some reason instead of the value in BUILD_VER ,"BUILD_VER" gets printed,
can anyone suggest why is it so?

```
@echo off
REM set $NetPath="Z:\Build_ver\build_ver.txt" 
set $NetPath="\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt"
set /p version=<\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt
set $BUILD_VER= %version%
echo BUILD_VER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
REM set $NetPath="Z:\Build_ver\build_ver.txt" 
set $NetPath="\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt"
set /p version=<\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt
set BUILD_VER=%version%
echo %BUILD_VER%
```

You need to encase variables in `%` (percent) symbols, to output their values.

I also took out the dollar symbol. If you included it the last two lines would be -

```
set $BUILD_VER=%version%
echo %$BUILD_VER%
```

It's just a bit redundant.